# Is there an order in which electricity goes off from the point of disconnection or fault?

Tags: power-supply, transmission-line

Have watched in a lot of movies, in scenes where their is a blackout and the power is going out like lets say for a country, the going off of the lights seems to follow a specific pattern.. so i was just asking.. with the *high speed* that electricity flows, is that the way it always goes out? do charges continue flowing like for a second or so even after a disconnection?

Answer (score 1):

In movies it just what looks better. In reality there is no storage for energy, so if power plant fails so badly that the other plants can't sustain supply, everything will blackout very fast. But it must really be a catastrophe, because normally it's not a single power plant, it's a network. If one fails, it is disconnected (google high voltage arc switch) and power flows from other generators.

Answer (score 1):

The power plants are connected in the same network that is similar to spider's net at first look. When a section of a powerline detects an overload it automaticaly disconnects, then the current in the net changes the path causing the other powerline sections to be overloaded, and shut down with the powerplants as well. Because of poweplants being disconnected the network sections are more and more overloaded and causing to colapse the entire network.
Obviously, this turning off is chaoticaly, there is no pattern.